# Array simple function that inserts dots before even numbers

Tags: javascript

```
function pArr(arr){
    var i;
    var wp = new Array;
    var l=arr.length;
    for (i=0;i<=l;i++){
        if (arr[i]%2==0){
            wp[i]=".";
            i=i+1;
        }
    else wp[i]=arr[i];}
} return wp ;

console.log(pArr[1,2,3,4]);
```

So it tells me the variable wp is not defined,  but I have done it... 
Thank you for your help

Comment: `return wp;` is outside the function...

Comment: And you are missing the invocation operator: `pArr([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it has to be inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic has some errors... I think you are looking after this:

```
function pArr(arr) {
  var wp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) wp.push('.');
    wp.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return wp;
}

console.log(pArr([1, 2, 3, 4])); // [ 1, ".", 2, 3, ".", 4 ]
```

You had the `return` outside the function, you where missing `()` to invoque the function and the way to add dots into the new array was mixed up.

Comment: I guess I can't increase the counter i by 1 inside the loop,  I'll check the push method

Comment: @user5723270 incrementing `i` will not make your array bigger. And you are already incrementing to loop with `i++`. Its just a pointer to the current array, not a new position inside it. `.splice()` could work for you but `.push()` is easier to understand I think.